# creating routine table for given array

Tags: mysql, grails

I have follwing data:

```
[[subject1,day1,time 1]],[subject2,day1,time2]]
```

and i want table structure as

```
        time 1          time 2
Sunday  subject1    Subject 2
Monday  subject1    Subject 2

<table id="routineClassTable" class="table table-condensed">
    <thead><tr>
        <td></td>
        <g:each in="${routineTime}" var="r">
        <td class='${r.id}'>${r.timetable.startTime.format("hh:mm")}-${r.timetable.endTime.format("hh:mm")}</td>
        </g:each>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <g:each var='d' in='${day}'>
        <tr>
           <td class='${d}'>${d}</td>
            <g:each in="${routineTime}" var="rt">

                   <g:each in="${subject}" var="sub">

                       <g:if test="${sub[1]!=''}"><g:set var="value" value="${sub[0]}"></g:set> </g:if>
                       <g:else>--</g:else>

                   </g:each>

                <td class="${d}${rt.id}">  ${value}
                </td>
            </g:each>
        </tr>
    </g:each>
    </table>
```

whats wrong in this table structure?It is displaying same subject in every column..help

Comment: Was the problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

From a glance, it looks like you have to move `<td>` inside `<g:each>`:

```
<g:each in="${routineTime}" var="rt">
    <g:each in="${subject}" var="sub">
        <g:if test="${sub[1]!=''}">
            <g:set var="value" value="${sub[0]}"></g:set> 
        </g:if>
        <g:else>--</g:else>

        <!-- Display each subject-->
        <td class="${d}${rt.id}">  ${value}</td>
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```

or simply:

```
<g:each in="${routineTime}" var="rt">
    <g:each in="${subject}" var="sub">
        <g:if test="${sub[1]}">
            <!-- Display each subject-->
            <td class="${d}${rt.id}">  ${sub[0]}</td>
        </g:if>
        <g:else>
            <td class="${d}${rt.id}"> --</td>
        </g:else>
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```